# ADT not able to create Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt

I am new to Android development and trying running my first application. My ADT is not able to run any emulator and giving following logs in LOGCAT : (Any help would be appreciated)

```
09-27 00:33:04.864: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): hwcomposer module not found
09-27 00:33:05.014: E/cutils-trace(36): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-27 00:33:06.834: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-27 00:33:07.374: E/cutils-trace(81): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-27 00:33:18.676: E/cutils-trace(37): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-27 00:33:22.364: E/logwrapper(224): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.444: E/logwrapper(225): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.494: E/logwrapper(226): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.556: E/logwrapper(229): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.638: E/logwrapper(232): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.724: E/logwrapper(233): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:22.754: E/logwrapper(234): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:27.564: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
09-27 00:33:27.704: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
09-27 00:33:27.704: E/Netd(33): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
09-27 00:33:27.704: E/Netd(33): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
09-27 00:34:36.667: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(287): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
09-27 00:34:38.834: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```